# $F=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}\dot q_i\dot q_j\implies\frac{\partial{\ F}}{\partial\dot{q_r}}=\sum_{j=1}^nc_{q_rj}\dot q_j$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, lagrangian-formalism, terminology

How does $F=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}\dot q_i\dot q_j\implies\frac{\partial{\ F}}{\partial\dot{q_r}}=\sum_{j=1}^nc_{q_rj}\dot q_j$?

The original source is https://www.kvi.nl/~scholten/AAM/Friction-Lagrange.pdf

[image]

Comment: Surely there's a better title for this than what's there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c_{ij}=c_{ji}$, we have

[\begin{array}{l}
F = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_i {\sum\limits_j {{c_{ij}}{{\dot q}_i}{{\dot q}_j}} } \\
\frac{{\partial F}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_r}}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_i {\sum\limits_j {{c_{ij}}\frac{{\partial ({{\dot q}_i}{{\dot q}_j})}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_r}}}} }  = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_i {\sum\limits_j {{c_{ij}}\frac{{\partial {{\dot q}_i}}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_r}}}} } {{\dot q}_j} + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_i {\sum\limits_j {{c_{ij}}{{\dot q}_i}\frac{{\partial {{\dot q}_j}}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_r}}}} } \\
 = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_i {\sum\limits_j {{c_{ij}}{\delta _{ir}}} } {{\dot q}_j} + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_i {\sum\limits_j {{c_{ij}}{{\dot q}_i}{\delta _{jr}}} }  = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_j {{c_{rj}}} {{\dot q}_j} + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_i {{c_{ir}}} {{\dot q}_i} = \sum\limits_j {{c_{rj}}} {{\dot q}_j}
\end{array}]

Comment: This answer (as does the reference) assumes that $c_{ij} = c_{ji}$.

Comment: We can always  assume that $c_{ij}=c_{ji}$ because  we can replace any non-symmetric $c_{ij}$ by $1/2(c_{ij}+c_{ji})$ without changing $F$.